# $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ for falling chain

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

There are several questions on Physics SE regarding the problem of a falling chain. However, to the best of my knowledge, no one has yet asked the following one. Consider the scenario presented in David Morin's Classical Mechanics textbook, where the right end of a chain with uniform mass density $\sigma$ is attached below a support while the left end is held and then released at time $t=0$. Assume that the length of the chain hanging below the support at $t=0$ is negligible.

[image: Fig. 5.28 from Morin's Class Mech]

The only force acting on the left part of the chain is its weight, since any tension would cause the kink (assumed to be massless) to accelerate upward with infinite acceleration. Therefore, we can write Newton's Second Law as follows:

\begin{align*}
F_{\text{weight}}&=\frac{dp_{\text{left}}}{dt}\\
F_{\text{weight}}&=m_{\text{left}}\frac{dv_{\text{left}}}{dt}+v_{\text{left}}\frac{dm_{\text{left}}}{dt}
\end{align*}

Since the chain is unstretchable, the displacement of any point in the left part of the chain is the same as that of the left end. Therefore, $v_{\text{left}}=\dot{y}$ and $\frac{dv_{\text{left}}}{dt}=\ddot{y}$. Moreover, $\frac{dm_{\text{left}}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sigma\left(L-\frac{y}{2}\right)\right]=-\frac{\sigma \dot{y}}{2}$.

We can now write:

\begin{align*}
\sigma\left(L-\frac{y}{2}\right)g&=\sigma\left(L-\frac{y}{2}\right)\ddot{y}-\frac{\sigma\dot{y}^2}{2}
\end{align*}

However, Morin states that the left part of the chain is in freefall, which implies $g=\ddot{y}$. Therefore, it seems that the term $-\frac{\sigma\dot{y}^2}{2}$ should not appear in the above equation.

But I cannot see a reason to ignore the term $v_{\text{left}}\frac{dm_{\text{left}}}{dt}$. Why should I?

Answer (score 2):

The falling chain problem has caused much discussion.

Experiment shows that your LH chain is *not* in free fall as the there *is* tension acting on the bend as dsiplayed  in my equation $(\star\star)$ below

Recent papers are C.~W.~Wong,  K.~Yasui, *Falling chains*,
American Journal of Physics 74  (2006) 490,  and the earlier M.~G.~Calkin, R.~H.~March, *The dynamics of a falling chain   I* ,  American Journal of Physics 57 (1989) 154.
Here  are my notes with  summary of those works.

Suppose a chain of total mass $M$ and  length $L$ is held with its two ends at the same height, and then the right-hand end is released so that it falls  smoothly downwards (this is the opposite hand to your picture, but if I edit  my notes I'll probably introduce more mistakes than I fix). Take as coordinate the distance that the end of the falling  the chain has descended. The mass per unit length is $\mu=M/L$ so, assuming that the fold is quite sharp,  the left and right  lengths of chain have masses
$$
M_R \simeq \frac{\mu (L-x)}{2},\nonumber\\
M_L \simeq \frac{\mu (L+x)}{2}.\nonumber
$$
Using these approximations the  Lagrangian ${\mathcal L}= KE-PE$ becomes
$$
{\mathcal L}= \frac \mu 4 (L-x)\dot x^2 +\frac{\mu g}{4} (L^2+2xL -x^2).
$$
Lagrange's equation
$$
\frac{\partial {\mathcal L}}{\partial x}= \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial {\mathcal L}}{\partial\dot x}\right)
$$
is therefore
$$
- \frac \mu 4 \dot x^2+ \mu g \frac{(L-x)}{2}= \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac \mu 2 (L-x) \dot x\right).
$$
We can write this more compactly as
$$
- \frac \mu 4 \dot x^2+ M_R g = \frac{d}{dt}\left( M_R \dot x\right)
$$
Performing the time derivative we have
$$
- \frac \mu 4 v^2+M_R g= \dot M_R v+ M_R \dot v, \quad (\star) 
$$
which rearranges to
$$
M_R \dot v= M_Rg+  \frac \mu 4 v^2.
$$

It is   tempting  to  think of the RH falling chain as a body moving a speed $v$ that is ejecting  mass  backwards at a rate
$$ 
|\dot M|= \frac{\mu v}{2}
$$
and at a relative speed $c=|v|$ so  that the ejected links  become stationary. The body is also acted acted on by $F_{\rm gravity} =M_Rg$.
If this were all that were  going on we could take the  thrust to be $|\dot M| c $ in the rocket equation
$$
M_R \dot v \stackrel{?}{=} M_Rg +   |\dot M| c\nonumber\\=   M_Rg +  \frac{\mu v^2}{2}\nonumber
$$
The rocket equation  implies that the  discarded links are creating a tension $T_R\stackrel{?}{=}{\mu v^2}/{2}$ at the fold which pulls the RH chain downwards.
This picture  is incorrect, however, because  it ignores the *upward*  pull of the tension in the LH chain which is also contributing to the  force decelerating  the  links to rest.  The left hand tension is the    $   \mu  v^2/4$ appearing on the LHS of  $(\star)$.  The  tensions at the two  sides of the  fold are   therefore $T_R= {\mu v^2}/{4}$, and  $T_L= {\mu v^2}/{4}$.

We can understand that $T={\mu v^2}/{4}$ on both sides of   the fold directly from $F=ma$ physics. Recall   that in the absence of gravity a  chain moving with speed $u$ can maintain an arbitrary planar shape because  the centripetal acceleration of its links is automatically  provided by the tension according to
$$
\frac{\mu u^2}{r}= \frac{T}{r}. \quad (\star\star)
$$
The tension takes the value $T= \mu u^2$  independent of the radius of curvature $r$.  For our falling chain, and  in the reference frame  that  is descending  with the fold at $u=v/2$, the chain is moving through the fold at   $u=v/2$. If we can ignore the effect of gravity and the non-inertial reference frame, the tension *throughout* the fold must be $T= \mu (v/2)^2=\mu v^2/4$. Ignoring these effects  is a safe approximation for our  sharp fold because  when $r$ is small the forces in $(\star\star)$ completely dominate all other forces.

The  force exerted on the hand holding the other end of the chain is the sum
$$
T_{\rm hand}= M_L g+ \frac \mu 4 v^2,\nonumber\\
= \frac {\mu (L+x)}{2} g +\frac \mu 4 v^2\nonumber
$$
of this tension at the fold and the weight of the hanging chain.
It  becomes infinite as $x\to L$.

Your textbook, and older textbooks such E.H. Love, *Theoretical Mechanics*, 3rd ed, CUP (1921), 261;
H.~Lamb, *Dynamics* 2nd ed. CUP,  (1923) Chap.
VII, Example XII.5, p. 149;
W.~Chester, *Mechanics* Allen and  Unwin, London (1979) Exercise 8.30,
p. 241.
cite Cayley's incorrect solution in *On a class of dynamical problems*, Proc. Roy. Soc. London 8 506-511 (1857).  which makes a mistake *opposite*  to the  rocket equation error by setting
$$
T_L\stackrel{\rm ?} {=}  \frac{\mu  v^2}{2},\quad  T_R \stackrel{\rm ?} {=}0.
$$
These tensions  allow  the RH chain to fall freely, $v=gt$, and correspond to  the links being abruptly decelerated  by an inelastic collision at the bend.  Cayley's solution is not in agreement with the experimental data of   Calkin and March.