Tension in a falling rope attached to a support
I came across this question and thought it was fairly simple.

Here is what I did:
The rope is slack at the lowest point. At t = 1, this point is at 2.5m below the support. we can say the tension is zero at that point. Now, as we go up the right part of the rope, the tension increases, and at the point of attachment with the support, the tension force acting is the weight of the right segment of the rope.
This however is not the right answer. What am I missing? Please provide me with an explanation so as to why the tension is not equal to the weight?

Most of the textbook solutions to this problem are wrong.  See the discussion at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754698/f-fracdpdt-for-falling-chain

oh okay. thanks
